# Match specific pattern only up until character using RegEx

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to create a RegEx to get the database, schema and table names from an SQL CREATE TABLE statement:

Example 1:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "finance"."invoices_1" (
    "abc" NUMBER(15,0),
    "def" VARCHAR2(200),
    "ghi" DATE
);
```

Example 2:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "commerce"."finance"."invoices_1" (
    "abc" NUMBER(15,0),
    "def" VARCHAR2(200),
    "ghi" DATE
);
```

The depth of the schema varies, so I'm trying to come up with a regular experession that match the names, whether they include the database name, schema name or only the table name:

```
\"[A-Za-z0-9_]*\"
```

Unfortunately, this also matches the column names. Is there a way to match this specific pattern only up until the first opening bracket?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different regex implementations.)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`"\w+"(?:\."\w+"){0,2}(?=\s*\()`

1. `"\w+"` -- any word text inside the double quotes (f.e. `"commerce"`)
2. `(?:\."\w+"){0,2}` -- optionally up to 2 times extended table name part (f.e. `."finance"."invoices_1"` or `."invoices_1"`)
3. `(?=\s*\()` -- [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to look for the opening bracket symbol (`(`)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0F6egD/1

Comment: This works as expected. Thanks! The only caveat is that I needed to turn off the global flag, otherwise I still had a few instances where it matched other items in the SQL DDL.